# Parsing Tabular Data with Regular Expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex, parsing

I'm writing an application in C# that parses some text files and gets info from them. I need to parse a tabular data like below and populate the info into the properties of a class.

I have no problem with table and column headers. I also can get the data using capture groups, but in some cases, some values may be empty (or may contain whitespaces, as in the 4th data line, Col6)

Sample :

```
===============================================================================
Table Header
===============================================================================
Col1         Col2      Col3 Col4 Col5       Col6
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
21           abc       xyz  xyz  1          blablabla
22           abc       xyz       1          bla-bla-bla
103          abc       xyz  xyz  1          
4000         abc       xyz  xyz  1          blabla bla
4001         abc       xyz  xyz  1
```

I have a pattern for data lines like this :

```
([\w\d\-_\.\*\#\:\\/\<\>]+)\s+([\w\d\-_\.\*\#\:\\/\<\>]+)\s+([\w\d\-_\.\*\#\:\\/\<\>]+)\s+([\w\d\-_\.\*\#\:\\/\<\>]+)\s+([\w\d\-_\.\*\#\:\\/\<\>]+)\s+([\w\d\-_\.\*\#\:\\/\<\>]+)?$
```

It works fine when all columns contain data.  When I add a whitespace char to the character class in the last capture group (for Col6), it begins to match two consecutive lines together. I need a line by line match. How can I do that?

The second question is, for many columns, I need "any char but space" approach and I use this pattern in a capture group : ([\w\d-_.*#:\/\<>]+)

If the data may contain whitespace, I'm adding a whitespace char to this pattern. Is this the right approach? Or would it be a problem in texts like this (e.g. column mismatches)?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a fix lenght between two cols or are there tab separated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done with regex.

To explain why, let's take the 2nd row in your data:

```
Col1         Col2      Col3 Col4 Col5       Col6
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
22           abc       xyz       1          bla-bla-bla
```

The way you're approaching this case could match "1" as Col4, with an empty Col5. There are no conditions to tell the regex engine that "1" is actually the 5th column. [Live example](https://regex101.com/r/nV0xS0/1)

Assuming data is fixed length, I suggest using [String.Substring()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

As for your **2nd question**:
Any char but space = `[^ ]` using a [Negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) 
Or you can use `\S` (any char but whitespace)

Comment: I think, max length of each column is fixed, so I decided to use this approach. Thanks for help